# Apache: Permanent redirect that is case-insensitive?

Tags: apache, redirect, case-insensitive

i have the following redirect:

```
RedirectPermanent /SCJ https://fin-iq.com
```

but it does not work for `/scj`, `/sCj`, etc. is there a way to make this case insensitive?

i tried adding [NC,L] but the page crashed.

thanks!

Comment: I believe this question is better suited for ServerFault.com

Comment: Just for the record, there's a better way than the selected as correct answer: `RedirectMatch permanent (?i)^/SCJ https://fin-iq.com` , taken from your same question in serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/167138/apache-redirecting-with-a-case-insensitive-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modifiers [NC,L] are for RewriteRule only. They don't apply to RedirectPermanent.

And the apache docu tells, that the first parameter to RewriteRule is case-sensitive

> The old URL-path is a case-sensitive
>   (%-decoded) path beginning with a
>   slash [1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

So I guess, the only option you got is:

```
RedirectPermanent /SCJ https://fin-iq.com
RedirectPermanent /SCj https://fin-iq.com
RedirectPermanent /ScJ https://fin-iq.com
RedirectPermanent /Scj https://fin-iq.com
RedirectPermanent /sCJ https://fin-iq.com
RedirectPermanent /sCj https://fin-iq.com
RedirectPermanent /scJ https://fin-iq.com
RedirectPermanent /scj https://fin-iq.com
```